# Laravel Migration - can not add foreign key

Tags: laravel

I try to migrate two tables in Laravel

Table 'Aitems'

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateAitemsTable extends Migration
  {
   /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function up()
   {
    //
    Schema::create('aitems', function($table) { 

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('item_id');
        $table->integer('listing_id');        
        $table->string('item_category');
        $table->string('item_name');
        $table->string('item_price');
        $table->string('item_description');
        $table->string('item_storing_address_1');
        $table->string('item_storing _address_2');
        $table->string('item_storing_suburb');
        $table->string('item_addr_long');
        $table->string('item_addr_lang');
        $table->timestamps();            
   });

    Schema::table('aitems', function($table){
        $table->foreign('item_id')->references('item_id')->on('itemfeatures');
        $table->foreign('listing_id')->references('listing_id')->on('itemfeatures');    
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::drop('aitems');
  }
}
```

Table 'itemfeatures'

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreateItemfeaturesTable extends Migration
 {
 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    //
    Schema::create('itemfeatures', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';    

        $table->increments('id');          
        $table->integer('listing_id')->unsigned();            
        $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('feature_id');
        $table->string('feature_description');          
        $table->timestamps();

    });
 }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::drop('itemfeatures');
}
```

}

I got the message of 'error of 1215 Can not add foreign key constraint' when trying to do the migration. Have looked into a lot of other forums and still can't figure what I have done wrong. Much appreciated any help out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables structure looks weird, but if you know what are you doing, fix columns in `aitems` table. Change this:

```
$table->integer('item_id');
$table->integer('listing_id');
```

To this:

```
$table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('listing_id')->unsigned();
```